# Custom Request Header in Flask app is missing but added in Backend Services GKE

Tags: python, flask, kubernetes

I'd like to add some elements for `Custom Request Header` on a Flask app. I deployed using GKE through Kustomize.

Initially, I added them in my k8s deployment such as:

`config.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: my-backend-config
spec:
  customRequestHeaders:
    headers:
    - X-XSS-Protection:1;mode=block
    - Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;preload
    - X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
    - X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
    - Content-Security-Policy:frame-ancestors 'none'
    - Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

The `customRequestHeaders` is successfully added in Backend Services as shown:

[image]

However, the header is not showing from the web itself:

[image]

Whereas the expected outcome:
[image]

What am I missing here? Should I add something on the code to retrieve the `customRequestHeaders` from Backend Services?

Comment: why you are checking into Response headers when you are adding headers into request headers.

Comment: however, i can see there is open issue in ingress-gce :https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/1268

Comment: I'm showing that Response header is somehow empty. It should appear somehow

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are checking for request headers on the client. But they are being added on the load balancer level, they won't be visible at the start. Check you [GKE logs](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/using-logs) to see if they are being added.